# This code keeps giving me: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep getting a TypeError: string indices must be integers. Not sure how to correct this.

```
def get_next_target(string):
    start_str=string.find('<')
    if start_str==-1:
        return None,0

    end_str=string.find('>',start_str)
    next_start_str=string.find('<',end_str)

    if next_start_str==-1:
        return string[end_str+1:]

    word=string[end_str+1,next_start_str]
    return word,next_start_str



print (get_next_target('<h1>Title <>'))
```

Comment: Python errors contain the exact line and line number where the error occurs. This would obviously be very helpful here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use a `,` for string slicing, which is causing this to become a `tuple`. You need to replace the `,` with a `:`

`word=string[end_str + 1:next_start_str]`